# Поиск пути в матрице с++

Tags: c++, матрицы, поиск-пути

Всем привет :)

Вопрос такой :
Имеется матрица вида

```
4 7
...*...
.......
..###..
...@...
```

где '@' - шарик ,который нужно переместить в '*'.Символ '#' - стена(через них ходить нельзя),через символ '.' ходить можно.
Задача заключается в том чтобы найти количество минимальных путей из @ в *.(например в данном примере кол-во минимальных путей == 6)

Мой алгоритм такой: сначала ищу всевозможные пути и записываю их в **path(путем будет 1,2,3,4,5...*)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого с помощью рекурсии иду с конца(с '*') до начала и на каждой итерации рекурсии проверяю есть ли еще какой нибудь путь,если есть то global_count_of_ways++ .

Проблема в том что это очень долго. При больших N(строки) и M(столбцы) вылезает time limit.

Вот код,который я написал

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
struct way {
    int visited;
    int count_way;
};
/* нахождение пути*/
void find_road(int n, int m, int row, int col, char** lab, int** visited, way** path, queue<int>& plan) {
    if (!visited[row][col]) {
        /* проверяем не вышли ли мы за границы лабиринта, есть ли клетка
        в массиве посещенных и можно ли через нее пройти*/
        if ((row + 1) < n && (row + 1) >= 0 && !visited[row + 1][col] &&
            (lab[row + 1][col] == '.' || lab[row + 1][col] == '*')) {
            path[row + 1][col].visited = path[row][col].visited + 1;
            path[row + 1][col].count_way += path[row][col].count_way;
            plan.push(row + 1);
            plan.push(col);
        }
        if ((row - 1) < n && (row - 1) >= 0 && !visited[row - 1][col] &&
            (lab[row - 1][col] == '.' || lab[row - 1][col] == '*')) {
            path[row - 1][col].visited = path[row][col].visited + 1;
            path[row - 1][col].count_way += path[row][col].count_way;
            plan.push(row - 1);
            plan.push(col);
        }
        if ((col + 1) < m && (col + 1) >= 0 && !visited[row][col + 1] &&
            (lab[row][col + 1] == '.' || lab[row][col + 1] == '*')) {
            path[row][col + 1].visited = path[row][col].visited + 1;
            path[row][col + 1].count_way += path[row][col].count_way;
            plan.push(row);
            plan.push(col + 1);
        }
        if ((col - 1) < m && (col - 1) >= 0 && !visited[row][col - 1] &&
            (lab[row][col - 1] == '.' || lab[row][col - 1] == '*')) {
            path[row][col - 1].visited = path[row][col].visited + 1;
            path[row][col - 1].count_way += path[row][col].count_way;
            plan.push(row);
            plan.push(col - 1);
        }
        visited[row][col] = 1; /* отмечаем клетку в которой побывали */
    }
}


int main() {
    int n, m, x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, x, y;
    queue <int> plan;
    cin >> n; cin >> m;
    char** lab = new char*[n];
    int** visited = new int*[n];
    way** path = new way*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lab[i] = new char[m];   /* массив для хранения лабиринта */
        visited[i] = new int[m]; /* массив для хранения информации о посещении клеток*/
        path[i] = new way[m];  /* массив для хранения найденных путей */
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            visited[i][j] = 0;
            path[i][j].visited = -1;
            path[i][j].count_way = 0;
            cin >> lab[i][j];
            if (lab[i][j] == '@') { /* находим начало пути*/
                x_start = i;
                y_start = j;
                plan.push(i);  /* заносим начальную клетку */
                plan.push(j);  /* в план посещения */
                path[i][j].visited = 1;
                path[i][j].count_way = 1;
            }
            else if (lab[i][j] == '*') { /* находим конечную точку */
                x_end = i;
                y_end = j;
            }
        }
    }

    while (!plan.empty()) { /* пока очередь посещения клеток непустая*/
        x = plan.front();
        plan.pop();
        y = plan.front();
        plan.pop();
        find_road(n, m, x, y, lab, visited, path, plan); /* продолжаем поиск пути*/
    }


    cout << path[x_end][y_end].count_way % 1000000007 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Вы знаете что такое метод динамического программирования? Именно он здесь может дать очень быстрое решение.

Comment: @Zealint А где именно тут можно применить динамическое прграммирование,чтобы было быстрее?
При поиске всех оптимальных путей ,или при их подсчете?

Comment: при подсчёте. В каждой ячейке нужно сохранить число способов дойти до неё (в изначальной ячейке ставим `1`), затем выполняем итерационный процесс: число способов попасть в некоторую ячейку равно сумме числа способов попасть в предшествующие ей (на кратчайшем пути). В итоге время выполнение составит порядка "О большое" от размера матрицы.

Comment: Что касается всех кратчайших путей, то они должны искаться одновременно с подсчётом методом поиска в ширину. То есть получается поиск в ширину сочетает в себе метод динамического программирования (подсчёта). Иными словами, в обычном поиске в ширину вы просто помечаете все вершины, входящие в кратчайшие пути из начала в конец, но тут в качестве их пометок выступает число способов.

Comment: Но есть ещё более простой для понимания способ. Можно составить матрицу смежности графа и возвести её в степень `k`, где `k` - длина кратчайшего пути (её можно посчитать заранее однократным поиском в ширину). Вы получите как раз в ячейке `(i,j)` этой матрицы число способов добраться из `i` в `j`, только беда в том, что у вас матрица смежности будет иметь размеры `N*M x N*M`. И тот способ, который я описал выше, он как раз чем-то похож на работу с разряжёнными матрицами, как будто бы мы выполняли умножение линейным методом, а не бинарным.

Comment: @Zealint Решил сделать как вы сказали и создал структуру way для хранения не только номера вершины но и количества путей в нее ведущих.
Некоторые тесты проходит нормально ,но в некоторых выдает неверный ответ(к сожалению неверные тесты посомтреть не могу).
Может быть вы сможете подсказать, что я неправилно сделал?
код обновил сверху

Comment: сказать по правде, не хочу копаться, а иначе уже написал бы полный ответ, но беглый взгляд показал, что вы неверно суммируете способы. Нужно не в конце брать ответ по модулю, а КАЖДЫЙ РАЗ, когда складываете числа, в противном случае получите переполнение.

Comment: Впрочем, я чувствую, что есть ещё ошибки. Я нигде не увидел, чтобы вы суммировали именно все кратчайшие пути, потому что как только вы посещаете клетку, она выбывает из очереди и вы туда уже не занесёте сумму из другого пути. В общем, я бы советовал взять хороший ручной тест и пройтись отладчиком, всё сразу станет ясно.

Comment: Подскажу только как правильно создать хороший ручной тест. Возьмите поле удобного для вас размера, для меня 6 на 6 было бы достаточно. Нарисуйте его на бумаге в клетку. Ткните куда-нибудь начало и конец, можно даже без препятствий (но только не на одной вертикали и горизонтали). Вычеркните все те клетки, через которые кратчайшие пути точно пройти не могут, получите только те, через которые проходят кратчайшие пути. То есть, глазом видно, какой длины будет путь и можно легко нарисовать ручкой область, все пути в которой будут кратчайшими. Продолжение в следующем комментарии.

Comment: Затем ставите единицу (число способов = 1) в начальную клетку. В остальных клетках нули. Далее распространяете эту единицу на всех соседей вдоль кратчайших путей. Заносите соседей в очередь. Все они - соседи первого порядка, до них длина пути равна 1. Далее в соседей второго порядка суммируете эти единички, пихаете их в очередь. Когда из очереди уйдут все соседи первого порядка, у вас останутся только соседи второго порядка (до них 2 шага) и в каждой такой клетке будет правильное число способов сделать эти два шага (там будут уже единички и двойки, видимо).

Comment: Далее соседей второго порядка превращаете в третьего - и так далее. В конце концов все нужные числа сойдутся в конечной клетке и вы туда просуммируете всё, что было нужно. На бумаге это дело 3-х минут, а потом запускаете отладчик и проверяете, что программа делает то же самое. Если оказалось, что программа права, ну усложните тест, добавьте на путях препятствие, увеличьте размеры. И так шаг за шагом найдете ошибку.

Comment: Чтобы найти k непересекающихся кратчайших путей из вершины в графе, достаточно применить модифицированный алгоритм дейкстры. Примеры реализации можно посмотреть тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519030/python-dijkstra-k-shortest-paths

Comment: В задаче автора пути могут пересекаться как по вершинам, так и по рёбрам. А алгоритм Дейкстры в данном случае не нужен, потому что граф не взвешенный. Слишком долго работать будет, поэтому здесь нужен именно поиск в ширину.

Comment: @Zealint Вчера доделал программу .Ошибка была только в переполнении . Взятие по модулю каждый раз решило эту проблему и все прошло. Но все равно большое спасибо!

Comment: По-моему такие задачи решаются поиском "в глубину" или "в ширину". В даном случае - "в ширину" будет оптимальнее.

Comment: @Arcanecliff , пожалуйста, но тогда зачем вы пометили чей-то неправильный ответ в качестве правильного? :)

Comment: @Zealint Ответы данные в комментариях не могут быть "приняты", топикстартер выбирает наиболее подходящий из неподходящих ответов, рекомендую вам написать свой ответ -- а потом попросить переставить галку. Также по теме: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7733

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define PATH std::vector<POSITION>
#define QUEUE std::queue<PATH>

int rows;
int cols;

int shortest_path_length;
int shortest_path_counter;

struct POSITION {
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool operator == (POSITION a, POSITION b) {
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
}

bool operator != (POSITION a, POSITION b) {
    return a.x != b.x || a.y != b.y;
}

POSITION start {};
POSITION finish {};

void check_position(POSITION verified_position, PATH current_path, QUEUE &paths) {
    if (verified_position.x < 0 || verified_position.x > cols) {
        return;
    }

    if (verified_position.y < 0 || verified_position.y > rows) {
        return;
    }

    if (verified_position == finish) {
        if (current_path.size() == shortest_path_length) {
            shortest_path_counter++;
        } else {
            shortest_path_length = current_path.size();
            shortest_path_counter = 1;
        }
    } else {
        if (std::find(current_path.begin(), current_path.end(), verified_position) == current_path.end()) {
            PATH new_path(current_path);
            new_path.push_back(verified_position);
            paths.push(new_path);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cin >> rows >> cols;

    bool graph[rows][cols];
    shortest_path_length = rows * cols;

    std::string line;
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        std::cin >> line;

        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            if (line[col] == '#') {
                graph[row][col] = false;
                continue;
            }

            if (line[col] == '@') {
                start = { col, row };
            }

            if (line[col] == '*') {
                finish = { col, row };
            }

            graph[row][col] = true;
        }
    }

    QUEUE paths;
    PATH path = { { start } };
    paths.push(path);

    while (!paths.empty()) {
        PATH current_path = paths.front();

        if (current_path.size() > shortest_path_length) {
            paths.pop();
            continue;
        }

        POSITION current_position = current_path.back();
        POSITION next_position { current_position.x - 1, current_position.y };

        if (graph[next_position.y][next_position.x]) {
            check_position(next_position, current_path, paths);
        }

        next_position.x = current_position.x + 1;

        if (graph[next_position.y][next_position.x]) {
            check_position(next_position, current_path, paths);
        }

        next_position.x = current_position.x;
        next_position.y = current_position.y - 1;

        if (graph[next_position.y][next_position.x]) {
            check_position(next_position, current_path, paths);
        }

        next_position.y = current_position.y + 1;

        if (graph[next_position.y][next_position.x]) {
            check_position(next_position, current_path, paths);
        }

        paths.pop();
    }

    std::cout << shortest_path_counter;

    return 0;
}
```